# Why are there variables in output of xgettext?

Tags: i18n

```
# SOME DESCRIPTIVE TITLE.
# Copyright (C) YEAR THE PACKAGE'S COPYRIGHT HOLDER
# This file is distributed under the same license as the PACKAGE package.
# FIRST AUTHOR <EMAIL@ADDRESS>, YEAR.
#
#, fuzzy
msgid ""
msgstr ""
"Project-Id-Version: PACKAGE VERSION\n"
"Report-Msgid-Bugs-To: \n"
"POT-Creation-Date: 2011-04-13 10:34+0800\n"
"PO-Revision-Date: YEAR-MO-DA HO:MI+ZONE\n"
"Last-Translator: FULL NAME <EMAIL@ADDRESS>\n"
"Language-Team: LANGUAGE <LL@li.org>\n"
"MIME-Version: 1.0\n"
"Content-Type: text/plain; charset=CHARSET\n"
"Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit\n"

#: test.php:4
msgid "Application"
msgstr ""
```

And when I run `msgfmt` just get warning that `CHARSET` not portable,why?

My source file is as simple as:

```
<?php
var_dump(function_exists('_'));
textdomain("mail");
print _("Application");exit;
```

Comment: You might try explaining a bit more about what you are running, where this output is coming from, the host system, etc.

Comment: @Caleb,the above is generated by `xgettext -o xxx file`,and when I run `msgfmt` on it,warning is got.I'm on linux.

Comment: I found this question by searching for the email address `LL@li.org` on a search engine... In fact it is just default data that can be replaced with yours, it was also generated with wp-cli tool for WordPress and the command `wp i18n make-pot`. But I am curious why the email address `LL@li.org`.
Edit: I searched for the WHOIS and it looks like the domain is registered by `Linux International`.
For your question about the charset, it is wrong because you used `charset=CHARSET` instead of something like `charset=UTF-8`.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps your input file isn't in the expected format and it is just passing data through? Try posting your source file (or at least some of it) to pastebin or somewhere for us to examine.

Comment: I've updated with the source file:)

Comment: Um...ok but that's definitly not the whole chain of code. What is the `_` function, what does it output, and where does gettext come into the mix? It sounds like we need to see the output that get's passed to xgettext, not some upper level controller code.

Comment: I've updated with the complete content of .po generated by `xgettext source-file` command.